Mybatis-plus v3.1.2 cannot correctly execute multi-column in combination query statements
I have tried using XML and @Select to construct SQL statements in mybatis, but errors still occur. From the error message, there is no problem with the constructed SQL syntax. This is what I am confused about.
dkpkMap: Map<Stirng, String>

select * from scloud_license_info
 <where>
     <foreach collection="dkpkMap.entrySet()" item="item" index="index"
              open="(product_key, device_key) in (" separator="," close=")">
         ( #{index}, #{item} )
     </foreach>
 </where>

The above execution results are as follows：
### Error querying database.  Cause: com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.exceptions.MybatisPlusException: Failed to process, please exclude the tableName or statementId.
 Error SQL: SELECT * FROM scloud_license_info WHERE (product_key, device_key) IN  (   (?, ?)  )
### The error may exist in com/skyworthdigital/thirdpartyP2P/mapper/SCloudLicenseInfoMapper.java (best guess)
### The error may involve com.skyworthdigital.thirdpartyP2P.mapper.SCloudLicenseInfoMapper.batchUpdateDeviceOfflineTimeByPKDK
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.exceptions.MybatisPlusException: Failed to process, please exclude the tableName or statementId.
 Error SQL: SELECT * FROM scloud_license_info WHERE (product_key, device_key) IN  (   (?, ?)  ); nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.exceptions.MybatisPlusException: Failed to process, please exclude the tableName or statementId.
 Error SQL: SELECT * FROM scloud_license_info WHERE (product_key, device_key) IN  (   (?, ?)  )
### The error may exist in com/skyworthdigital/thirdpartyP2P/mapper/SCloudLicenseInfoMapper.java (best guess)
### The error may involve com.skyworthdigital.thirdpartyP2P.mapper.SCloudLicenseInfoMapper.batchUpdateDeviceOfflineTimeByPKDK
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.exceptions.MybatisPlusException: Failed to process, please exclude the tableName or statementId.
 Error SQL: SELECT * FROM scloud_license_info WHERE (product_key, device_key) IN  (   (?, ?)  )
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1324)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1036)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:949)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:932)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:751)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:700)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

